# Gaussian distribution of AR(1) model

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, autoregressive

This is very basic, but I have been stuck here for a while.

> Consider an AR(1) model $Y_t = c+\phi Y_{t-1} +\epsilon_t$, where $c$ is a constant. If $\epsilon_t \sim i.i.d. N(0, \sigma^2),$ then $Y_1, \dots, Y_T$ are also Gaussian, where $Y_1$ is the first observation in the sample.

I don't quite understand how we have each single realization of $Y_t$ Gaussian. It seems that the conditional distribution $Y_t|Y_{t-1}$ is Gaussian, but why $Y_t$ is Gaussian unconditionally?

Comment: For last question: Because $Y_{t+1}$ and $\epsilon_t} are normal distributed. See here for proof. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalSumDistribution.html

Comment: @a_statistician Wait, why $Y_{t+1}$ is Gaussian?

Comment: typo. Should be $Y_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_t$ are normal, so their linear combination (one of them is $Y_t$) is normal according to linked site.

Comment: @a_statistician How do you know $Y_{t-1}$ is normal?

Comment: Think from beginning when $t=1$. Then $t=2$ ... $t=t-1$

Comment: Actually, I am confused. When $t=1$, do we assume $Y_0=0$ so that $Y_1$ is a normally distributed random variable? If this is the case, then it does follow that $Y_{t-1}$ is normal.

Comment: That is what I think ($Y_0 = 0$). I am not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to be confused here.  Strictly speaking, the asserted conclusion in the highlighted statement is a *non sequiter*.  (Can you please add the source of the statement?)  The element $Y_1$ is defined recursively in terms of $Y_0$ in the specified recursive equation.  Since there is no specification of the distribution of $Y_0$, the distributions of the observable values is not determined.

What they *should have specified* is that $Y_0 | \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \sim \text{N}.$  Unfortunately, people are notoriously sloppy in setting up time-series models, and it is commonly the case for the model to not be properly specified.  With a bit of practice you get used to "reading between the lines" to figure out what was intended.

Comment: Actually, specifying that $Y_0$ is Gaussian without also saying that $Y_0$ is independent of all the $\varepsilon_i$'s (or at least jointly Gaussian with all the $\varepsilon_i$'s) is also sloppy because without such a clause, $Y_1 = c + \phi Y_0 + \varepsilon_1$ is not necessarily Gaussian: the sum of two marginally Gaussian random variables is not Gaussian unless joint Gaussianity is also assumed. Perhaps it is simpler to set $Y_0=0$ and avoid the extra complications.

Comment: Good point - edited.

Comment: Also, specifying $Y_0=0$ has the drawback that you lose stationarity, so that is not particularly desirable.