# Standardizing an AR(1) Model

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, autoregressive, standardization

Given an AR(1) model:
$X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$

where $\varepsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_X)$ and $\phi$ is a constant such that $|\phi| < 1$.

My Question is, If you standardize this AR(1) model what will be the general formula? and is the resultant form normally distributed?

Comment: Can you explain what *standardizing the model* means?

Comment: Sorry, normalizing the data from the AR(1) model. Just like given a data set X_1,...., X_n, one would have a standardized dataset by subtracting the mean and dividing by sigma.

Comment: Normalizing and standardizing is not the same. Here you have standardizing. No, you do not obtain normality by changing the location and the scale of the original distribution.

Comment: Originally the AR(1) data from the defined equation should be normally distributed. Also check a similar post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373020/gaussian-distribution-of-ar1-model